# checking file exists or not by using javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-7-x64

Good Evening Everybody,

May be my question is not correct format,How to check if file is exits or not in particular drive by using JavaScript(without using ActiveXObject)
                Expalin me with simple example .
Thanking You,
Santosh.

Comment: What JavaScript environment? WSH? Node? HTA? A browser?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple answer. This is not possible you cannot look if a File is available on your Harddrive. You can do this for server's via ajax but not for the local pc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming local Jscript because of the Windows tag; you cannot do it without creating an FSO instance;

```
var exists = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists("c:\\foo\\bar.qux");
```

Comment: ActiveXObject is only supports in only IE.I want browser compatability.